# Configuring static files (CSS) in Java11 Appengine project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to port my Java Servlet project to App Engine. I can't get my CSS file to deploy correctly.Below is my configuration and my `app.yaml` configuration. What am I doing wrong?

[image: app.yaml]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change handler url of  webapp. it has to be like this:

```
handlers:
  - url: /webapp/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|js|css|json))$
    static_dir: webapp\1
```

It uses regex for those files resides in nested folders

Answer (score 0):

```
handlers:
# All URLs beginning with /stylesheets are treated as paths to
# static files in the stylesheets/ directory.
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
  # ...
```

Picked from  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref#handlers_element)